# Python, instead of a list of 40 million consecutive numbers how would I make a 2-d list of 40, size 1 million, consecutive number lists?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I am working on a MapReduce algorithm currently and I need to build my data source a little better. This program is to give a list of nonces to use in a hash algorithm to find "good" (low value) hashes; very similar to bitcoin. Right now I make a single list of 40 million consecutive numbers (nonces). But the overhead in IO (using mincemeat.py) is making the program very slow.

Currently I am using this to create my list

```
#Build the data source
nonces = [i for i in range(0, 400000)]
#Create a dict with a single entry
datasource = dict(enumerate(nonces))
```

How could I alter the first line of code to create a list of size 40, containing lists of size 1 million; so the first list would be 1-1mil, then 1mil to 2mil, etc? Do I need to break down and make a for loop, or is there a simple one liner I could implement to achieve this?

Here is how I would implement the for loop to do it, can it be condensed? (I know I have repeating numbers..)

```
nonceList = []
for j in range(0, 40):
    nonceList.append([i for i in range(j*1000000, (j+1)*1000000)])
datasource = dict(enumerate(nonceList))
```

Comment: All these numbers are trivial to generate in batches in your mapreduce methods instead. Why generate them all up-front and in memory?

Comment: Hmm, so pass a list of size 40, and use a multiplier in my Map function? // I generated them upfront because I am naive still.

Comment: Exactly; generate numbers like these as needed, not all at once.

Comment: Quick question, for the python md5 library. Once I do a `.digest()` will the hash be "empty" so that if I were to do another update it would not use information from the previous updates? (so I dont recreate a new md5 object every iteration of my loop)

Comment: No, the hash is not empty; you can continue to add data to it.

Comment: Looking at the library documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html there is no way to clear the previous data is there? I need to instantiate a `.new()` md5 each iteration?

Comment: You'd create a new MD5 hashing object, yes.

Comment: Ok thank you!, if you want make a small "answer" to this question so I can give you your Internet points.

Comment: Note that the `.digest()` documentation states: *Return the digest of the strings **passed to the `update()` method so far.***, emphasis mine. This implies that more `update()` calls can be made still.

Comment: I used the `copy()` method. So I make a md5 with my starting value (my name) and then do a `copy()` for each iteration of the for loop and just `update` with my nonce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't produce consecutive numbers up front; just have your mapreduce tasks produce them from a starter number.

E.g. for 40 tasks, number those 0-40 and use a multiplier to generate numbers in the task; in Python 2, use `xrange()` to generate numbers, as `range()` will produce a list, materializing a million integer objects for no gain.